# How to update a label at a regular interval?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

The problem is appearing to be notoriously stubborn to me.

I am trying to update the label (referred to as lbl in the code below inside the while loop) every second. The problem is label is not updating. The code is not throwing any error message either.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

TIMER_START_MIN=5
TIMER_START_SEC=5*60
min,sec=divmod(TIMER_START_SEC,60)
banner_text="{:02d}:{:02d}".format(min,sec)

def timer_func():
    global reset_button
    global lbl
    global TIMER_START_SEC
    global banner_text
    reset_button.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)

    while(TIMER_START_SEC>0):
         mins,secs=divmod(TIMER_START_SEC,60)
         banner_text="{:02d}:{:02d}".format(min,sec)
         lbl.config(text=banner_text)
         TIMER_START_SEC=TIMER_START_SEC-1

root=Tk()

top_frame=Frame(root)
top_frame.pack(side=TOP)

bottom_frame=Frame(root)
bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

lbl=Label(top_frame,text=banner_text,font=('Helvetica', 36), fg='black')
lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)

start_stop_button=Button(bottom_frame,text="START",font=("Helvetica",24),command=timer_func)
start_stop_button.grid(row=0,column=0)

reset_button=Button(bottom_frame,text="RESET",font=("Helvetica",24))
reset_button.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This type of question has been asked probably a hundred times on this site. Did you do any research? If you did, and you didn't find anything, can you share what search terms you used? Maybe we can make the answer to this question easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a blocking loop in a GUI, since is blocks the GUI's loop. Therefore it looks like it's locked up since you've blocked it from responding. You need to use tkinters `after` method to add your code to the GUI mainloop.

```
import tkinter as tk

TIMER_START_MIN=5
TIMER_START_SEC=5*60
min,sec=divmod(TIMER_START_SEC,60)
banner_text="{:02d}:{:02d}".format(min,sec)
time_left = TIMER_START_SEC

def timer_start():
    reset_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    timer_update()

def timer_update():
    global time_left
    if time_left > 0:
        mins,secs=divmod(time_left, 60)
        banner_text="{:02d}:{:02d}".format(mins,secs)
        lbl.config(text=banner_text)
        time_left -= 1
        root.after(1000, timer_update)

root=tk.Tk()

top_frame=tk.Frame(root)
top_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP)

bottom_frame=tk.Frame(root)
bottom_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

lbl=tk.Label(top_frame,text=banner_text,font=('Helvetica', 36), fg='black')
lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)

start_stop_button=tk.Button(bottom_frame,text="START",font=("Helvetica",24),command=timer_start)
start_stop_button.grid(row=0,column=0)

reset_button=tk.Button(bottom_frame,text="RESET",font=("Helvetica",24))
reset_button.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I also got rid of your evil wildcard import and fixed the typo in your update function from "min, sec" to "mins, secs".

Comment: wildcard imports aren't "evil", they are just not the preferred way.

Comment: Except when they *are* evil and haunt you in your dreams.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for everything: a helpful explanation and a complete working coding example!